# MYSQLI Insert blob (image) into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, blob

I'm trying to insert an image into my database via PHP and SQL. I've managed to do it so far, but only with a PDO connection. I'd rather use a MYSQLI connection since the rest of my application uses it. Under here you see it working with a PDO connection, I commented out the mysqli one, since it didn't work. Is there any way to make mysqli work with blobs?(upload image to mysql)

```
function changeAvatar($conn, $userId, $file, $filename, $filesize, $filetype){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO avatars (usersId, avatars.name, avatars.image, size, avatars.type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $userId);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $filename);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $file);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $filesize);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $filetype);
    $stmt->execute();





/*$sql = "INSERT INTO avatars (usersId, avatars.name, avatars.image, size, avatars.type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
    header("location: ../profile.php?error=stmtfailed");
    exit();
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isbis", $userId, $filename, $file, $filesize, $filetype);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$_SESSION["avatar"] = $file;
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
header("location: ../profile.php?error=none");
exit();*/}
```

Here is the code where I actually run the function:

```
 case "avatar":
    $userId = $_SESSION["userid"];
    $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    changeAvatar($conn2, $userId, $file, $filename, $filesize, $filetype);
    break;
```

My question: How do you do this with mysqli?
(I'm new to PHP and SQL so there could be some flaws in here.)

Comment: What happens when you try to use the mysqli-version? I would like you to edit your question so you have code for one PDO-version and code for one MySQLi so it's easier to figure what you're actually using. I would also like to know you're defining the actual $conn.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php
This helped me

Comment: MySQL might not be liking the binary data that is an image. You can try `base64_encode` of the binary data. When you display the data you can use the encoded data directly with `<image src="data:image/png;base64, ... " />` (replace ... with encoded data).

Comment: MySQLi doesn't report errors by default and you don't fetch them manually: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting

Comment: @DavidFairbanks How did you reach that conclusion? We have a BLOB column that works from PDO and MySQLi provides a `b`  ("corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets") type specification char.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález without the table definition and the error message I'm making an assumption/guess.